# Double output within Drupal function

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I'm going crazy

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

// Nothing here

$var = 'bla-bla';
print_r($var);

// Nothing here

}
```

I see on the screen **bla-blabla-bla**

WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have two forms on the page. Try printing (better yet, install [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and use dpm) $form_id instead of $var and see which forms are involved.

Comment: Yep that's it exactly. hook_form_alter() runs on every single form, so you've got more than one form on the page you're viewing.

Comment: Thanks for replay Scott Reynen, Dave Reid: To clarify, the variable placed inside if ($form_id == 'user_login') {} statement, I did't write it in the code above, sorry

Answer (score 1):

hook_form_alter works on every form. You probably have the search form in this page, so it prints the text twice (one for every form).

In order to add changes to only one form, use the $form_id argument like this:

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'YOURFORMID') {
    $var = 'bla-bla';
    print_r($var);
  }
}
```

change YOURFORMID to your form_id.

You can find the form_id by looking on the HTML of the form output and search the value of the input that his name is 'form_id'.